# Cosmos DB local emulator - what's the simulated RU?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Today, I'm hitting the throttling limit on my local Cosmos DB emulator with a *Too Many Requests* response within a `StorageException`, which I'm pleased about since it's best to hit errors in dev.

I can find the option to turn rate limiting off `/DisableRateLimiting` but nothing to control what the limit is; there's no `/ThroughPut`-like switch.

Does anyone know what RU value is on the emulator?

Comment: `The emulator is not a scalable service and it doesn't support a large number of containers. When using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, by default, you can create up to 25 fixed size containers at 400 RU/s (only supported using Azure Cosmos DB SDKs), or 5 unlimited containers.` - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. I was just on that page but searching for "RUs" not "RU/s" :)

Comment: There is the usual option in the emulator's data explorer UI to set each database to a specific RU setting, or autoscale. If you're looking for a command-line only method, not sure if that's available.

Comment: @NoahStahl this is the correct answer, if you want to add a proper answer. It sounds silly but I've never really looked around the Explorer in the browser to find the scale settings as I tend to use other tools and only ever need to clear all data anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the RU throughput setting for a database in the emulator, you can do so via the data explorer.

Open Data Explorer from the tray icon (Windows):

[image]

Select or create a database, then configure within Scale:

[image]